# Is it possible to emulate a network between my device and my desktop?

Tags: android, windows, networking

I'm developing an app and I need to use my network to access some webservices. I was connecting on WiFi and it was ok but I think that a system administrator should have blocked the incoming connections in my desktop.

I want to know if I can find an app to simulate a network between my desktop ( Windows 7 ) and my Android device.

Do you know if it's possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody put a locket, than has a reason. Easier to talk with him. If he don't want... than  use an USB to Wi-fi adapter and the WI-FI connection is ready :)

Comment: @DavidL. use your Administrator phone for ADHOC :)